# Is there a way to remove indirect formula completely?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I am trying to eliminate or reduce the `indirect` functions in this code.

Someone mentioned offset but none of the tutorials I found were comprehensive enough to explain how to implement `Offset` with this dynamic `Index-Match-Match` formula. I understand that `Offset` is volatile too but as another mentioned 1 offset compared to 3 indirect will help.

Here is the code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"Payroll'!"&"$A:$ZZ"), MATCH($B$2, INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"Payroll'!"&"$A:$A"),0), MATCH($A9, INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"Payroll'!$1:$1"),0)),"")
```

If I can use VBA to eliminate the need for this formula, how do I do that?

Comment: That looks like indirect is being used to combine a filename with the cell address, I don’t think that can be done with offset and I ended up with indirect to build refereces to 6 different workbooks - but will be interested if I am wrong.

Comment: Not file name. worksheet name within same workbook.

Comment: Offset is indeed volatile but orders of magnitude more performant than Indirect. That said, your question should be posed in a minimal manner to be as broadly useful as possible. As posted, it is difficult to respond to and not very useful to our community. Can you winnow it down? I ask because I believe Offset will work - you'd still need one Indirect (to address the variable Sheet name) but the rest could be addressed using offset. e.g. =Offset(Indirect("SheetName!A1"),1,1) will return the contents of cell SheetName!B2.

Comment: @JohnJoseph I apologize i was only trying to make the formula more efficient processing-wise.  How can I winnow it down so that is easier to be understood. Still getting the hang of posting on here.